# how to get username from organization id?

Tags: authentication

I have a couple of org which I used before and started getting Developer script exception emails every 10 minutes from the schedule I set up. I don't remember what I used to login to this org but know the userid / org id. how can i get username and relogin to the system so that I can turn off this email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Technical Support, request a password reset for your account in the org by that org ID matching the email address that you're receiving those notifications at. They can't give you the username (I'm pretty sure), but if the email address on the user account matches your email account, they are allowed to reset the password so you can login again (the email will also include your username).